# How to remove the "links_" property in Spring

Tags: java, spring, hyperlink, format, response

I'm using Spring Boot to build a web service. When my api returns a collection of objects, "_links" properties are added. Is there anyway to return collection without them?

My response:

```
{"links":[],"content":[{"id":2,"bssid":["Eduo","Konfere"],"rssi":[55.04,63.03],"x":55.04,"y":66.05,"links":[]},{"id":3,"bssid":["TPLINK","MANTOR"],"rssi":[25.23,95.02],"x":51.01,"y":52.03,"links":[]}]}
```

What i'm looking for:

```
{"content":[{"id":2,"bssid":["Eduo","Konfere"],"rssi":[55.04,63.03],"x":55.04,"y":66.05},{"id":3,"bssid":["TPLINK","MANTOR"],"rssi":[25.23,95.02],"x":51.01,"y":52.03}]}
```

Code of my controller:

```
@GetMapping(value="/points", produces = "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
Resources<Resource<Points>> all() {

    List<Resource<Points>> points = repository.findAll().stream()
            .map(point -> new Resource<>(point)).collect(Collectors.toList());

    return new Resources<>(points);
}
```

Will appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 0):

`_links` property is most likely added by [Spring HATEOAS](https://spring.io/projects/spring-hateoas). If you don't want to use it simply exclude it from your project dependencies.

Comment: The thing is if i exclude "<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
        </dependency>" from my maven pom.xml, the other parts of HATEOAS like Resources won't work properly.

Comment: + i have spring.hateoas.use-hal-as-default-json-media-type=false , on my application.properties